# Using where method with specific time versions on a class with Paper_trail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I'm auditing the state column of the User model with PaperTrail. I need to search all entries with the state "active" BUT at a specific time in history. Something like this:

```
User.where('version_at(time).state = ?', "active)
```

PaperTrail has that version_at(date) method but it is an instance method and I could not find a class one.

Currently I'm doing the following but is highly inelegant and it does thousands of queries to get what I need:

```
assigning_users_ids = []
  User.each do |user|
    if user.version_at(@date).state == "active"
      assigning_users_ids << { user_id: user.id, profile_id: user.profile_id}
    end
  end
```

Now I have all the user ids and profiles in an array and I need to separate them by profile:

```
  @assignable_starter_ids = []
  @assignable_general_ids = []
  @assignable_pro_ids = []
  @assignable_reduce_ids = []
  assigning_users_ids.each do |a|
    case a[:profile_id]
    when Profile.starter.id
      @assignable_starter_ids << a[:user_id]
    when Profile.general.id
      @assignable_general_ids << a[:user_id]
    when Profile.pro.id
      @assignable_pro_ids << a[:user_id]
    when Profile.reduce.id
      @assignable_reduce_ids << a[:user_id]
    end
  end
  @assignable_starter = User.where(id: @assignable_starter_ids)
  ...
```

Edit1: This is an example query as a result of .user.version_at(@date)

```
PaperTrail::Version Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `versions`.* FROM `versions` WHERE `versions`.`item_id` = 1 AND `versions`.`item_type` = 'User' AND (`versions`.`created_at` > '2016-01-01')  ORDER BY `versions`.`created_at` ASC, `versions`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
```

Edit2: This is version_at method in PaperTrail files:

```
def version_at(timestamp, reify_options={})
  # Because a version stores how its object looked *before* the change,
  # we need to look for the first version created *after* the timestamp.
  v = send(self.class.versions_association_name).subsequent(timestamp, true).first
  return v.reify(reify_options) if v
  self unless self.destroyed?
end
```

PaperTrail stores how and object looked before the audited change.So, it looks for the first version saved AFTER the given time. It there is a version it creates the object (without saving it) as it was at that file. If there is no new version, it returns the current object as it is. I'm lowering my expectations...

Also, PaperTrail saves all the object attributes in one string...

Comment: Can you add an example query paper trails is doing as a result of `user.version_at(@date)`?

Comment: Sure! I'm updating the Question. Thanks!

Comment: There is something like `User.preceding` and `User.subsequent` which take two params: object or timestamp and true if first arg is timestamp. So I think `User.preceding(Date.today-1.year, true)` should get you all users a year ago (but I have nowhere to test it so you need to try). It also returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` so you should be able to chain `.where(state:'active')` to it.

Comment: Thanks Michal, Unfortunately I cannot find any of those methods. I looked for them at the docs and forums and I tried several combination in the console. Is not working neither with the user class or instance nor the Version class or instance...

Comment: So `User.preceding(Date.today - 1.year, true)` raises `NoMethodError`?

Comment: Unfortunately. It raises NoMethodError: undefined method `preceding' for #<Class:0x007f851d4a1420>

Comment: Ok, `Papertrail::Version` includes `PaperTrail::VersionConcern` [(source)](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/frameworks/active_record/models/paper_trail/version.rb)  and the `VersionConcern` has `module ClassMethods` including `subsequent`, `preceding`, `where_object`, etc. So either I don't know Rails/Ruby or something is missing in here.

Comment: But definitely `Papertrail::Version.subsequent()` should work

Comment: what does `User.first.send(self.class.versions_association_name)` return?

Comment: It returns: NoMethodError: undefined method `versions_association_name' for Object:Class. Papertrail::Version.subsequent() works but bring all versions created after specified time.

Comment: `preceding` and `subsequent` are class methods of `Papertrail::Version`, not `User`.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to search all entries with the state "active" BUT at a specific time in history.

You could start by finding version records in a given time range.

```
start_time = Time.utc(2016, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)
end_time = Time.utc(2016, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0)
versions = ::User.
  versions.
  where_object(state: "active").
  between(start_time, end_time)
```

You can then "reify" these version records to get `User` objects.

```
versions.first.reify # => a User object
```

It's not exactly what you want, but should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Jared. But the "reify" method is for each version. I cannot use it to do a single query to the DB. As far as I understand is not to different with the user.each version_at(date) I'm using for. Am I missing something?